# What do I use instead of tensor.dataSync() to get the predicted value in tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm currently trying out linear regression in tensorflow js. I'm inputting x-values into a predict function and getting y-values using dataSync(). Is there a way I can do this asynchronously so it's quicker? The x-values are inputted by plotting points on a canvas.

Here's a part of the code:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000, 600);
    canvas.style.border = '1px solid blue';

    m = tf.variable(tf.scalar(random(0)));
    b = tf.variable(tf.scalar(random(0)));

}

 let ys = tf.tidy(() => predict(curveX));
        let curveY = ys.dataSync();
        ys.dispose();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asynchronous code does not execute faster, synchronous code stops processing while waiting for I/O and the opposite is true for asynchronous code.

**tf.dataSync()** downloads the values from the tensor synchronously, while **tf.data()** downloads the values from the tf.tensor() asynchronously and returns a promise, so that is what you're looking for.

```
const getPrediction = async (curveX) => {
    const prediction = predict(curveX)
    return await prediction.data()
}
```

Comment: is it possible to access the predicted value right away with tf.data()?

Comment: Yes it works the same as tf.dataSync() but it's asynchronous so wrap it in an async function and await the result.

Comment: wait sorry I'm pretty clueless here. Would this work:
let curveY2 = async() => {
            return await ys.dataSync();
        }
curveY2.then(); do I put the x-values in here?

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the sample code for it. It should work although as you did not include the predict function() I am assuming it just returns the prediction from the model.